# Unable to access domain.com/phpmyadmin giving me 404 error

Tags: database, centos7, http-status-code-404, phpmyadmin

I hope you are fine.

I installed for more than one year Vesta in my CentOS 7 everything is working fine, but a few days ago I cant access phpmyadmin.

In the past, I just go to Vesta click on phpmyadmin and open the 1.2.3.4/phpmyadmin, but now when I click on that the ip 1.2.3.4/phpdomain is redirected to domain.com/phpmyadmin with one 404 error.

I already try with https://1.2.3.4/phpmyadmin but is not working, the page cannot be display.

If you have any idea will be great I need to delete the actual DB and create 3 new one, this is my phpinfo lakompra.com/phpinfo.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a RewriteRule or a redirect, so please look in your conf file under directive settings or in the .htaccess file or in the phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php for the value `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']`

I hope this helps